How to change volume of text to speech voice for SpeechSynthesizer objects in Azure CognitiveServices SDK without changing system volume in c#
I am using c# and the text to speech Azure SDK. The voice is very loud relative to other sounds and that is a problem. I can't use this capability unless I can change only the TTS volume. I found this URL:
SpeechSynthesizer.Properties. I usually find Microsoft's new documentation very helpful, but that is about worthless. There are properties, but absolutely no way to determine what those properties are. Many of the voice objects are like this. Properties with API for getting known properties and setting them, but no way to know what those properties are.
I'm aware of the volume level in the mixer. Is that the only way to do it? Programmatically access the mixer controls and change the one for the application? If so, that presents other problems because that same application plays other audio that needs to be balanced with this.

You can use SSML to adjust volume and other speech output    characteristics.
The volume attribute of the prosody tag sounds like what    you’re looking for.  Here’s an example from this link:
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
    <voice name="en-US-AvaMultilingualNeural">
        <prosody volume="+20.00%">
            Enjoy using text to speech.
        </prosody>
    </voice>
</speak>

This link has an C# example of how to construct the SSML and     use it to adjust speech output properties. You’ll need to scroll     down a bit to see it.

Thanks! I'll check it out let you know how it goes. Likely the accepted answer. I was hoping for a pure C# solution without SSML, but if that's the only way, I can live with that.

@Vector - you bet!  I revised my answer to include another option.

This link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=windows%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-csharp leads me to believe that the only way to get access to the underlying Prosody instances used by Azure text to speech is via the SSML (Option 1) posted above. I can find no way to gain access to any Prosody instance or feed the Speech API one of my own instances.

My mistake.  Option #2 is for a different use case - missed that when reviewing the doc the first time.  I'll remove it from my answer.

The code is a little ugly, but that's OK.. I was very antimicrosoft for many years due to hostile dispositions in the tech community and market, especially when it came to the open source community, regardless of how much $$ they donated to education and students in an attempt to manipulatively "hook" up and coming Computer Science students on their tech. MS did a 180, and so did I. I now support and promote Microsoft cloud products, services, and languages wherever I go and I am very influential in my field. This small inconvenience is easy overlook. Thank you for your help. Best wishes cdub!
